# javascript displaying button values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display value and `data-value` from my button. Its not displaying anything. Its only displays `var grade = $(this).val();` if I don't include var cs `$(this).data("data-value");`

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" name="grade" value="<?php echo " $cs1"; ?>" data-value="CPS210-CompSci-I (4)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education  "></span> Grade
</button>
<script>
    $('button[name="grade"]').click(function() {
        var grade = $(this).val();
        var cs $(this).data("data-value");
        if (grade == "") {
            $('#grade').html("<h4> Fail or no grade received for "+cs+" " + grade + "</h4>");

        } else {
            $('#grade').html("<h4> Grade received for " +cs+" " + grade + "</h4>");

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seriously, you are not seeing anything weird in this code? `var cs $(this).data("data-value");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var cs = $(this).attr("data-value");`

Comment: or ```$(this).data("value");```